# Function to map an image to 3D point by point

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, graph

I am trying to map my image point by point to 3 dimensional space.

For example, if my original image has intensity of 100 at location `X`, I want to plot this point in 3D location `Y` with intensity of 100. I want to repeat this steps for every point/pixel, and get a final image. My biggest problem is that I want to do it point by point.

I appreciate any comments or advice. Thank you.

=======================

p.s.

As I was writing this question, I just came up with an idea. I know how to print 'whole' image into certain location/shape in 3D by using `warp()` function. Instead of using my whole image as an argument to warp function, if I give one point intensity value and one 3D point as arguments for warp function, and repeat this steps for every image point, will I get a descent looking final image in 3D? If there is a better function to use, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean? You wanna use image as texture?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean by using image as texture. Shai probably gave me an answer what I was looking for. I will try scatter3() function. I was looking for similar answers to what Shai wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for [`scatter3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html):

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
[x y]=meshgrid(1:size(I,1), 1:size(I,2));
scatter3(x(:),y(:),I(:),15,I(:),'filled');
axis tight; colormap gray
```

And this is what you get (after some changes to view point):

[image]

PS,
I used a single `scatter3` command to plot all the points at once. You may (I have no idea why you would like to do so) do it one by one

```
 figure;
 for ii=1:numel(x)
     scatter( x(ii), y(ii), I(ii), 15, I(ii), 'filled'); 
     hold on; % need this!
 end
 axis tight; colormap gray;
```